# How to validate unicode "word characters" in Python regex?

Tags: python, regex, django, django-forms

I have form with field:

```
name = forms.RegexField(regex=r'\w+$', label=u'Name', required=True)
```

but if I type special chars (ś for example) form not pass is_valid() function. How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Activate [Unicode matching](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.U) for `\w`.

```
name = forms.RegexField(regex=r'(?u)\w+$', label=u'Name', required=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of defining the regex as a string, you can compile it to a regex object first, setting  the [re.U](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.U) flag:

```
import re

name_regex = re.compile(r'\w+$', re.U)
name = forms.RegexField(regex=name_regex, label=u'Name', required=True)
```